# Express OOP + Typescript issues: TypeError in userService?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, authentication, oop

I am currently developing a full authentication app with the MERN stack, all in typescript. But I am running into some problems (type Error) with my userController file.

This is my routes file:

```
import { validate } from "../middlewares/validateMiddleware";
import { createUserSchema } from "../schemas/user.schema";
import { UserController } from "../controllers/user.controller";


function routes(app: Express) {
  app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.json({ message: "Hello World" });
  });

  // Local User Authentication and Authorization
  const user = new UserController()
  app.post("/auth/local/signup", validate(createUserSchema), user.createNewUser)
}

export { routes };
```

user controller file

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { UserService } from "../services/user.service";
import { createUserInput } from "../schemas/user.schema";
import { CREATED, FORBIDDEN } from "http-status";
import log from "../utils/logger";
import { JwtStrategy } from "../auth/jwt";
export class UserController {
  private userService: UserService;
  private jwtStrategy: JwtStrategy;

  constructor() {
    this.userService = new UserService();
    this.jwtStrategy = new JwtStrategy();
  }

  public async createNewUser(
    req: Request<{}, {}, createUserInput["body"]>,
    res: Response
  ) {
    try {
      const user = await this.userService.createNewUser(req.body);
      return res.status(CREATED).json(user);
    } catch (error) {
      log.error(error);
      return res.status(FORBIDDEN).send(error);
    }
  }

  public async authenticateUser() {}
}
```

userservice file:

```
import { User, UserInput } from "../models/user.models";
export class UserService {
  private model: typeof User;

  constructor() {
    this.model = User;
  }

  public async createNewUser(dto: UserInput) {
    try {
      return await this.model.create(dto);
    } catch (error: any) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

But I always get the error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userService')

What could be the problem here?

```
      "type": "TypeError",
      "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userService')",
"stack":
          TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userService')
              at /Desktop/Practices/Ts/Mern-Auth/src/controllers/user.controller.ts:21:31
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am relatively new to using express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lost `this` context

You have a few options

Arrow function

```
app.post("/auth/local/signup", validate(createUserSchema), (...args) => user.createNewUser(...args))
```

Bind

```
app.post("/auth/local/signup", validate(createUserSchema), user.createNewUser.bind(user))
```

Bind in the constructor

```
constructor() {
  this.userService = new UserService();
  this.jwtStrategy = new JwtStrategy();
  this.createNewUser = createNewUser;
}
```